# Get the type of a NLTK Tree()

Tags: python, indexing, tree, nltk

I am using NLTK's Semcor module:

```
nltk.download('semcor')
from nltk.corpus import semcor
```

`semcor.tagged_sents()` iterates over the same sentences with additional annotation including WordNet lemma identifiers.

```
semcor.tagged_sents(tag="sem")[0]
>>> [['The'],
 Tree(Lemma('group.n.01.group'), [Tree('NE', ['Fulton', 'County', 'Grand', 'Jury'])]),
 Tree(Lemma('state.v.01.say'), ['said']),
 Tree(Lemma('friday.n.01.Friday'), ['Friday']),
 ['an'],
 Tree(Lemma('probe.n.01.investigation'), ['investigation']),
 ['of'],
 Tree(Lemma('atlanta.n.01.Atlanta'), ['Atlanta']),
 ["'s"],
 Tree(Lemma('late.s.03.recent'), ['recent']),
 Tree(Lemma('primary.n.01.primary_election'), ['primary', 'election']),
 Tree(Lemma('produce.v.04.produce'), ['produced']),
 ['``'],
 ['no'],
 Tree(Lemma('evidence.n.01.evidence'), ['evidence']),
 ["''"],
 ['that'],
 ['any'],
 Tree(Lemma('abnormality.n.04.irregularity'), ['irregularities']),
 Tree(Lemma('happen.v.01.take_place'), ['took', 'place']),
 ['.']]
```

When I use indices in this list, I get the following output:

```
semcor.tagged_sents(tag="sem")[0][1][0]
>>> Tree('NE', ['Fulton', 'County', 'Grand', 'Jury'])
```

When I use one more index, I get the tokens from the list as output:

```
semcor.tagged_sents(tag="sem")[0][1][0][0]
>>> 'Fulton'
```

My goal is two-fold:

What code can I use to get the Lemma as output? So the output would be:

```
>>> Tree(Lemma('group.n.01.group')
```

And what code could I use to get the type of tree as output? In the case of this example:

```
>>> 'NE'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
semcor.tagged_sents(tag="sem")[0][1].label()
#'group.n.01'

semcor.tagged_sents(tag="sem")[0][1][0].label()
#'NE'
```